# Trying to refactor and avoid "argument mismatch, cannot convert to SomeClass" when using generics in this way

Tags: java, generics

Alright, so to start things off and give context - i'm refactoring some old code, and have decided on a "0 warnings, 0 lint warnings" rule. Meaning any warning will crash the build...

So, my current problem is with raw-typed lists. Let me post some code to give better context:

```
public abstract class Event implements Cloneable {
  // contents of this class aren't very important
  private long timestamp;
}

public interface EventObservable<T extends Event> {
    List<T> pollEvents();

    List<T> subscribe(EventCallback<T> callback) throws UnsupportedOperationException;

    boolean unsubscribe();
   // more less-significant methods
}

public abstract class AbstractEventObservable<T extends Event> implements EventObservable<T> {
  // nothing very significant
}

public class SomeEventObservable extends AbstractEventObservable<SomeEvent> {
  // storage, helpers, and overriding AbstractEventObservable methods
}
```

And everything works fine when they various `EventObservable`s are added to a `List<EventObservable>`.
I'm trying to change that to `List<EventObservable<Event>>` to get rid of the warning about using a raw-type `EventObservable`. This list is created and filled up only once...

However, when I change this line:

```
final List<EventObservable> list = new ArrayList<>(8);
```

to either of these:
`final List<EventObservable<Event>>`
or
`final List<EventObservable<? extends Event>>`
or
`final List<EventObservable<? super Event>>`

this bit here is the first thing to sound the alarm:

```
private List<EventObservable<? extends Event>> getEventObservablesList(...) {

            list.add(getDeviceInfoEventObservable(...)); // returns DeviceInfoEventObservable extends AbstractEventObservable<Event>

            list.add(getInstalledAppsEventObservable(...)); // returns InstalledAppsEventObservable extends AbstractEventObservable<InstalledAppsEvent>

            list.add(getAppInstalledEventObservable(...)); // returns AppInstalledEventObservable extends AbstractEventObservable<AppInstalledEvent>

            list.add(getAppUninstalledEventObservable(...)); //returns AppUninstalledEventObservable extends AbstractEventObservable<AppUninstalledEvent>

            list.add(getNetworkSwitchEventObservable(...)); //returns NetworkSwitchEventObservable implements EventObservable<NetworkSwitchEvent>
```

I'm kinda trying to apply PECS here, but at some point i need to both produce and consume the list. I need to fill it up with EventObservables of different events, and even when i use `EventObservable<? extends Event>` in places where i add them to the list, and use `EventObservable<? super Event>` in places where i just iterate through the list, at some point i hit the `List<EventObservable<? extends Event>> cannot be assigned to List<EventObservable<? super Event>>

So, whats my best approach here?

- "Break" these generic classes so they all return Event instead of their actual event type? that's a rather lame solution and isn't much better than suppressing the "rawtypes" warning
- use `? extends Event` in half of the code that produces, and `? super Event` in half of the code that iterates through the list and have the ugly "extends" -> "super" cast somewhere?
- i don't have many other ideas atm really. I still don't really get why some things just don't click together, like not being able to return `List<EventObservable<Event>>` from a method that expects to returh `List<EventObservable<? extends Event>>`. Like, why can't a `List<String>` be returned from a method that wants to return a `List<Object>` for example.
- just use raw-typed EventObservable like it was and suppress the warnings

Any suggestions are welcome.

The implicit, hidden question is also "How do i bridge between `List<EventObservable<? extends Event>>` and `List<EventObservable<? super Event>>` ? I'm really trying to avoid `List<EventObservable<?>>` since somehow that's no better than suppressing the warning to me. They're all going to have different kinds of `Event`s in them. So that's why i'd like for `Event` to show up in there as well, because `EventObservable<?>` looks like it can technically accept anything, even Strings.

EDIT:

I cannot really post a MCVE, but the flow goes something like this:

- the initialization class creates `EventObservable` of different types of Events. This list is created only once, upon initialization.
- that list is passed to another clsas, `EventCollector` which just keeps it.
- `EventSubscriber` iterates over `EventCollector::observableList` and subscribes to each of them, keeping a `List<EventObservable>` privately. It's the same instance as EventCollectors.
- periodically, the list of subscriptions is iterated and polled, and the gathered list of events is given to the serialization layer to serialize each of those events into a JSON, then the JSON is given to the networking layer for sending.

The code actually works fine, and tests pass. But they're raw-typed and i'd like to change that, by maybe having `<? extends Event>` on one end, and `<? super Event>`, something like that - or better.
Now i'd like to get rid of the warnings after turning them all on, and my options are:

- suppress the warning
- refactor in a less-than-ideal way so the warnings go away
- redesign these pieces and rewrite them

I'm not looking at redesigning this whole thing, and using `EventObservable<?>` doesn't look much better than suppressing the warning, but it certainly is a less-than-ideal refactor so the warning goes away. OR maybe not, i dunno yet, i'll know when i apply that to everywhere where raw-typed `EventObservable` is used.

Here is some code to illustrate the point:

```
public class Initialization class {
   private List<EventObservable> observableList; //i would like to avoid rawtype here

   private List<EventObservable> initList() {   //similar comment applies here
       List<EventObservable<Event>> list = new ArrayList()

       list.add(getSomeObservable(...)); //this works fine, because SomeObservable has a Event generic type, since it returns different types of Events

       list.add(getOtherObservable(...)); // this breaks down, because OtherObservable emits Event2

       list.add(getYetAnotherObservable(...)); //this breaks too, because YetAnotherObservable emits Event3

       return list;
    }

    public init()  {
      // unnecessary stuff
 
      observableList = initObservableList(...);  // this also breaks in different ways depending on how i declare observableList and return type of initObservableList()

     // more stuff
   }

   private SomeObservable getSomeObservable() { ... }

   private OtherObservable getOtherObservable() { /* instantiate OtherObservable */ }

   private YetAnotherObservable getYetAnotherObservable() { /* same */ }


   private void test() {
      EventObservable<Event> bla = getOtherObservable() // works fine
      EventObservable<OtherEvent> bla2 = getOtherObservable() // doesn't work, required type EventObservable<OtherEvent>, provided OtherObservable


      EventObservable<OtherEvent> bla3 = new AbstractEventObservable<OtherEvent> { ... }
      EventObservable<Event> test = bla3; // fails, required type EventObservable<Event>, provided EventObservable<OtherEvent>


      // sanity tests just to refresh my memory on generics
            List<Number> numbers;
            List<? extends Number> numbers2;
            List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            List<Float> floats = new ArrayList<Float>();
            numbers = floats; //nope, required type List<Number>, provided List<Integer>
            numbers.addAll(integers); //fine
            numbers.addAll(floats); //fine

            numbers2 = floats; 
            numbers2.addAll(integers); //nope, Required Collection<? extends capture of ? extends Number>, provided List<Integer>
      
   }
}


public class SomeObservable extends AbstractEventObservable<Event> {
  // unnecessary contents
}

public class OtherObservable extends AbstractEventObservable<OtherEvent> {
  // same as above
}

public class YetAnotherObservable extends AbstractEventObservable<YetAnotherEvent> {
  // ditto
}

public abstract class Event { /* mentioned above */ }
public class OtherEvent extends Event { ... }
public class YetAnotherEvent extends Event { ... }
```

So, do i'd rather go with `EventObservable<Event>`, rather a list of those however that's being troublesome.
And if i start using `List<EventObservable<? extends Event>>` then i open a whole new can of worms when i change return types of it's getter - the `initList()` method. Even if i use `<? extends Event>` everywhere (well, where in the bunch of files where I tried), I eventually hit a point where a method returns a bounded wildcard and is being given to another method that takes a bounded wildcard, however it says that capture#1 and capture#2 may differ.

So i'm guessing i shouldn't return wildcards anywhere. So now i'm thinking it might be "easiest" to just break these 3 observables and make Event their generic type. I'm out of clever ideas.

Comment: And for what it's worth, i am looking at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) too

Comment: `List<EventObservable<?>>` (or `List<EventObservable<? extends Event>>`) should work. Can you show a [mcve] of "at some point i hit the `List<EventObservable<? extends Event>>` cannot be assigned to `List<EventObservable<? super Event>>`" error? Where is "at some point"? You are not showing any code that tries to do an assignment like that.

Comment: sure thing sweeper, i'll post more attempts of what didn't work... I don't really want to use `List<EventObservable<?>>` since thats not anyhow better than just using it raw-typed or suppressing the warning. If i'm gonna parametrize it - which i want to do - i want `Event` to show up in there too.

Comment: Umm... `List<EventObservable<?>>` is literally the same as `List<EventObservable<? extends Event>>`. I can understand if you want to include `Event` for readability, but it sounds like you don't understand how wildcards without a bound works.

Comment: @Sweeper But the reason i ommited all that code is  this - there's a main initialization class which populates this list. Then it instantiates a different object which assigns that list to a private member, and is being used for iterating over. If the initialization class uses `<? extends Event>` and the other class uses `<? super Event>` thats where the problem you're not seeing (and asking for code) happens. So the implicit, hidden question is also "How do i bridge between `List<EventObservable<? extends Event>>` and `List<EventObservable<? super Event>>`

Comment: @Sweeper could be that i don't, could be that the non-bounded wildcard could be anything and will never conform to iterations such as `for (EventObservable<Event> item : observablesList) { ... }` too.  but then again, none of these will, so there might be more refactors in plenty places i don't quite forsee at this moment.

Comment: _How_ does the other class "use `<? super Event>`"? It is simply not type safe to assign one to the other.

Comment: They were all just using raw-typed EventObservable. The initialization class fills it up, then passes it to some other class which stores it, then some third class iterates through that list, saves the events to db and the "sending" layer serializes all these `Events` that it gets into a JSON and passes it to the "networking" layer for sending. So nobody really cares what kind of `Event`s are in there. lemme add this to the question too...

Comment: but i'm looking to make it type-safe, and the easiest thing to explain it is - `"I have this list, of differently-typed EventObservables<>, which is being filled up by one class and iterated by another class, and only the EventObservable themselves are being consumed from that list on a single-basis.`

Comment: but to answer your question @Sweeper - there is no `<? extends Event>` or `<? super Event>` anywhere yet. it's pretty much all raw-typed. and i'm trying to put them in in appropriate places to address this warning in a cleaner way than just pushing it under the rug.

Comment: added more code.